# excel - how to count number of names in a column, name is specified in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, countif

I have two worksheets, "Clients 2014" and "Receipts 2014".

The receipts have client names for each row (each row is a receipt).
[image: Receipts Table]

The search key is in the "Clients 2014" worksheet.
[image: Clients Table]

I want to count the number rows in the Receipts 2014 worksheet that contain the value in `'Clients 2014'!$A2`.

I tried using `CountIF('Receipts 2014'!$C$4:$C$300, $A$2)` in cell `'Clients 2015'!$D$2` but I get an incorrect value of 1, even though there are over 5 entries with the name.

In searching the web, the examples use string literals in the name.  I have a column of names in the Client's table and want to paste the formula into Column D for each row.

So, how do I count the number of receipts that contain the Client Name that is in cell $A$2 of the Clients 2014 table?

Comment: The formula you suggest yourself (`=COUNTIF('Receipts 2014'!$C$4:$C$300, $A$2)`) should work, it certainly does when I try to do the same with some dummy data. Are you sure that all the names in column C of your receipts-worksheet is spelled the same way, doesn't have any whitespaces you haven't noticed in them, etc? Apart from something like that, I can't see what would cause the formula to fail.

Comment: @eirikdaude is quite right. OP, try using `Trim` function in your criteria for `Countif`: `CountIF('Receipts 2014'!$C$4:$C$300, Trim($A$2))`

Comment: I agree that it sounds like the search value doesn't exactly match all the entries in your list. I'd suggest checking that all your data in `Receipts 2014` are sanitized. Use Find/Replace to replace double spaces with single spaces. Use `Trim() in another column to remove all leading and trailing spaces and then copy/paste that over the original data. You can also try copying the `Client Name` data to a new worksheet, use Remove Duplicates, and then sort the list so you can manually search for duplicates like "John_Doe" vs "John_ _Doe"

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem but... When you said  'Clients 2015'!$D$2 you meant 'Clients 2014'!$D$2, right?